# Having SignIn issues with Amplify-js with a react-native project. TypeError: cannot read property 'USER_ID_FOR_SRP' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-cognito, amplifyjs

**Describing the Issue**

After switching to Amplify from cognito-js ive come across a problem thats been very tricky for my level. i finshed setting up all the Auth. methods (signup, signin, forgetpassword, send code, ...). i managed to get the signup sequence working without a hitch. but the problem is with SignIn. when i enter the username and password, i get an error saying **ComputeModPow** of undefined. After looking at the issues raised against it on their github page and doing the workarounds suggested, which are that i install amazon-cognito-identity-js, link it and build and run again. upon doing this i come to my issue **"USER_ID_FOR_SRP"**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'USER_ID_FOR_SRP' of undefined
    at CognitoUser.js:270
    at Client.js:55
    at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
    at core.js:123
    at JSTimers.js:289
    at _callTimer (JSTimers.js:146)
    at _callImmediatesPass (JSTimers.js:194)
    at Object.callImmediates (JSTimers.js:458)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:135 "error"
```

**To Reproduce**

i tired to see if this was an issue and created a brand new npx react-native init today and it gave me the **ComputeModPow** error and was fixed after i installed amazon-cognito-identity-js.

so my guess is its an issue with my project. so i request anyone to help me to figure it out.

**Which versions of Amplify, and which browser / OS are affected by this issue?**

```
"OS: Ubuntu 19.04",
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.0.15",
"aws-amplify": "^1.1.40",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.19",
"npm": "6.10.2",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
```

OS and Browser aren't affected i think because on a bare-bones react-native app this worked the was it was supposed to.

Comment: @unSensi: ran into the same issue today. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but i has being solved.

In my case I had these lines of code in one of my files;

```
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;
```

Also, you can look through these repos:

1. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10128
2. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3612
3. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3682#issuecomment-569433173
4. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4016#issuecomment-539455465

Comment: In addition, this may also happen if you are debugging with react-native-debugger